# CSS transition on parent div causing absolute child divs to jump?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I am working on a circular hamburger menu button that animates on hover, growing from center, with the three bar child divs centered within the parent div circle.

The parent div has fixed positioning to enable the "grow" effect. The three hamburger menu lines are absolutely positioned divs.

When hovering, everything animated via transition is going great, except the three child divs jump from **bottom right** on hover and **top left** on mouse out. I've tried tweaking the margins, width/height, and positioning, but I am stuck. What am I missing?

```css
.circle-nav {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  top: 35px;
  left: 35px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  background-color: rgb(136, 35, 24);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -webkit-border-radius: 22px;
  -moz-border-radius: 22px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  transition: width 300ms ease, height 300ms ease, transform 300ms ease, background 300ms ease, border-radius 300ms ease, box-shadow 300ms ease, top 300ms ease, left 300ms ease;
}
.circle-nav:hover {
  width: 66px;
  height: 66px;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  background-color: rgb(187, 53, 39);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 8px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -webkit-border-radius: 33px;
  -moz-border-radius: 33px;
  border-radius: 33px;
}
.top-bar,
.mid-bar,
.bot-bar {
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 11px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.top-bar {
  top: 14px;
}
.mid-bar {
  top: 21px;
}
.bot-bar {
  top: 28px;
}
.circle-nav:hover .top-bar {
  top: 24px;
}
.circle-nav:hover .mid-bar {
  top: 31px;
}
.circle-nav:hover .bot-bar {
  top: 38px;
}
.circle-nav:hover .top-bar,
.circle-nav:hover .mid-bar,
.circle-nav:hover .bot-bar {
  left: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-nav">
  <div class="top-bar"></div>
  <div class="mid-bar"></div>
  <div class="bot-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because you are transitioning the container's dimension change but are not applying the equivalent transition to the position change of the bars. Because of this, the bars jump to their new position based on the original size of the container on hover in (meaning, it moves to bottom right as the `top` and `left` values are larger) and jump to their original position within the enlarged container on hover out (meaning, it moves to top left as the `top` and `left` are smaller). The bars do eventually move to the center at the end of the transition because the container is stretched from all directions.

If you add an equivalent 300ms `transition` to the bars then all looks fine.

Note that there was still a small jump in the left position of the bar but that can be resolved by adjusting the `left` position of the container on hover (like I have done in the snippet).

```css
.circle-nav {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  top: 35px;
  left: 35px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  background-color: rgb(136, 35, 24);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -webkit-border-radius: 22px;
  -moz-border-radius: 22px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  transition: width 300ms ease, height 300ms ease, transform 300ms ease, background 300ms ease, border-radius 300ms ease, box-shadow 300ms ease, top 300ms ease, left 300ms ease;
}
.circle-nav:hover {
  width: 66px;
  height: 66px;
  top: 25px;
  left: 24px; /* changed this to prevent the small adjustment during hover */
  background-color: rgb(187, 53, 39);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 8px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -webkit-border-radius: 33px;
  -moz-border-radius: 33px;
  border-radius: 33px;
}
.top-bar,
.mid-bar,
.bot-bar {
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 11px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all 300ms ease; /* added this to prevent the jump */
}
.top-bar {
  top: 14px;
}
.mid-bar {
  top: 21px;
}
.bot-bar {
  top: 28px;
}
.circle-nav:hover .top-bar {
  top: 24px;
}
.circle-nav:hover .mid-bar {
  top: 31px;
}
.circle-nav:hover .bot-bar {
  top: 38px;
}
.circle-nav:hover .top-bar,
.circle-nav:hover .mid-bar,
.circle-nav:hover .bot-bar {
  left: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-nav">
  <div class="top-bar"></div>
  <div class="mid-bar"></div>
  <div class="bot-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Harry for this. I opted out of this option and instead am using scale at the moment. But I appreciate the fix. With my menu being a checkbox, I wasn't sure if this was going to work out because of a couple other variables. I will look into this more later.

Comment: @Ce.: The solution should work with checkboxes also but scale transform is definitely the better option in my opinion. I assumed that you didn't want to use it for some reason.